# Elasticsearch match field=value (not contains)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, full-text-search, elasticsearch-rails

I have problem while searching through elasticsearch.
I have index `product` with fields `title` and `gender`

When I make query with `default_field: title` I need to get results only with `gender=male` (not female or others)

query: `dress AND gender:male`

Results contain both genders: `male` and `female` and `male,female`

It seems to me that `gender:*` search all which contains `male`, but not full match of value. How to do the query right?

I use it through Ruby on Rails

```
Product.search({
      query: {
        query_string: {
            query: query,
            default_field: "title"
          }
        },
        size: per_page,
        sort: [ _score: { order: relevance } ]
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According with [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elasticsearch-replicating-googles-double-quote-exact-match-query/97027) I just need to put value in double quotes..

`query = '(dress) AND (gender:"male")'`

do not forget to escape them if needed `"gender:\"male\""`

Answer (score 0):

Is gender a `keyword` data type? I suspect that you left/set the default mapping to the `gender` field (i.e., text + keyword subfield). In this case, try the following query: `dress AND gender.keyword:male`

Comment: Thank you, but double quotes were the solution